# Comparing the sum with total storage space

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to compare the total amount of products stored in one warehouse with the sum of items that is present in that warehouse. So far I have this (telling me how many of one product is stored in one of the warehouses)

```
select warehousename, pname, sum(numitems)
from oswarehouse join osshelf on whid=warehouseid
join osstored_in using (sid,whid) 
join osproduct  using (pid)
group by warehousename, pname
```

and now I would like to compare that with this select statement (which just tells me the total amount of products stored in that warehouse.

```
select sum(numitems) from oswarehouse 
join osshelf on whid=warehouseid 
join osstored_in using (sid,whid) group by warehousename
```

Is this possible if yes how? I've tried

```
having sum(numitems) > (select sum(numitems) from oswarehouse 
join osshelf on whid=warehouseid 
join osstored_in using (sid,whid) group by warehousenameect
```

but that just leads to nonsense because the select statement above returns multiple values(?).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, qualifying the column references so it is clear where they come from would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Would CTE do any good? Something like this:

```
with 
tfirst as
  -- This is your first query
  (select warehousename, 
          pname, 
          sum(numitems) sumnum
   from oswarehouse join osshelf on whid=warehouseid
   join osstored_in using (sid,whid) 
   join osproduct  using (pid)
   group by warehousename, pname 
  ),
tsecond as
  -- This is your second query; I included WAREHOUSENAME so that I could
  -- join TSECOND to TFIRST
  (select warehousename, 
          sum(numitems) sumnum
   from oswarehouse 
   join osshelf on whid=warehouseid 
   join osstored_in using (sid,whid) 
   group by warehousename
  )
select a.warehousename,
       a.pname,
       a.sumnum
from tfirst a join tsecond b on a.warehousename = b.warehousename
where a.sumnum > b.sumnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should learn to qualify your column references so it is clear what table they come from.  That makes it much simpler for other people (and perhaps you in the future) to follow the logic you have written.

That said, the only difference between the two queries -- in terms of the values being returned -- is the join to `osproduct`.

This `join` can only change the results if one of two things occur:

- Rows get filtered out because `pid` does not match.
- Rows are duplicated because `pid` is duplicated in `osproduct`.

The second condition we can eliminate, assuming that `pid` is the primary key in `osproduct` -- and that seems like a very reasonable assumption.

The first can be eliminated assuming that the column is never `NULL` in the referencing table and has a proper foreign key relationship.

Hence, I don't see particular value to what you are trying to do.  A solid data model ensures that the values returned by the queries are consistent.